# Selenium is not able to find any element on specific webpage using XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, not in an iframe and has been loaded

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

I am fairly new to Python and Selenium, but I have been able to navigate through many webpages via Selenium just fine. But a site recently changed their html code and now Selenium is not able to find *any element* on the page. Specifically I would like to click the Export-button, which is a `span` inside an `a` inside many `div`s.

This is the page: https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/power-schottky/products.html#

I am using the Selenium Chromedriver on Windows 10 with Python.

I have tried every selector I know (Rel XPATH, Abs XPATH, CSS-Selector, name, ID, link text, ...) but I always get `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`.

The website does use iframes, but as I see it, the Export-button is not inside an iframe. Also, while trying to test, I was not able to find the iframes with Selenium. Really any element besides the body can not be found anymore. I am making to make sure the element is loaded, but the error message appears even while waiting for the element, because Selenium can't find it.

Here is an example using the relative XPath, but I have not had any success with Css-Selector or anything else, or any other element:

```
# setup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# setup
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions ( ) ;
prefs = { "download.default_directory" : mypath };
options.add_experimental_option ( "prefs", prefs );
options.add_experimental_option ( "excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"] )

options.add_argument ( '--headless' )
driver = webdriver.Chrome ( executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe', options = options );

driver.get ( https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/power-schottky/products.html# ) 

# wait
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='st-site']/div[3]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a/span")))


# download
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='st-site']/div[3]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a/span"))
```

Which gives me the timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 228, in the_magic
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='st-site']/div[3]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a/span")))
    line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

If I make sure to wait for the webpage to be loaded with `time.sleep(30)` and skipping the `WebDriverWait`, the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 231, in the_magic
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='st-site']/div[3]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a/span"))
    line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='st-site']/div[3]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a/span"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=110.0.5481.178)
```

I don't really know what to try anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, there is no Export button at all on the page, or you need to provide steps-to-reproduce how to get one.

Comment: @DannyBriskin There clearly is an Export-button, directly visible when visiting the page, and I obtained the XPath via copying its XPath from the elements console.

Comment: @alexschrada - Hope you are clicking the 'Accept Cookies' button before searching for the desired element(Export button)?

Comment: @Shawn This may be it. Maybe the Cookie-alert shows up for Selenium, but not in my browser. However, I am also not able to click (or wait for) the "Accept Cookies" button neither via XPath nor CSS-Selector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Export button disappears upon zoom/unzoom, but okay, I have found two of them. I guess you need the one that is not hidden. The issue is in hidden spaces/EOLs in the Export span text. Here you go, the XPath

```
//div[@class='stsel-selector-ctn']/descendant::a/span[normalize-space(text())='Export']
```

In order to force webdriver completely mock user browser usage, please add following options (use your paths)

```
# setup
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--disable-site-isolation-trials")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=E:\\!!!!\\prof")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess")
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks for your work, but I still get the same NoSuchElementException with this XPath. So far, exactly 0 XPaths I have tried have worked for any of the elements on the page, I am really confused. 

Where did you find the hidden Export-button?

Comment: as I told you, there is something with your page, so the button is deleted from the DOM. or you need to wait until the page(and the button) is loaded completely, That's may be the reason. Second button can be found using  //a/span[normalize-space(text())='Export'] XPath (without leading div)

Comment: I definitely waited for the button to be loaded completely. The problem is not exclusive to the Export-button, but really any element on the website.

Comment: oh my, there is a bunch of security headers at the website that is not used by webdriver, let me edit the response with some additional options

Comment: Not sure I can follow you here. I get the error message that Google Chrome is not allowed to write or read into mypath, and if I comment out that line, I still get the access denied screen.

Comment: make sure that  --user-data-dir=<your path> is a writable folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, this is the closest I could get. Below code manages to go past <kbd>Accept Cookies</kbd>. And it manages to click on <kbd>Export</kbd> button as well. However, I think the application is detecting the automated software as it is not allowing to download.

```
# options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/power-schottky/")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept Cookies']"))
driver.get("https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/power-schottky/products.html#")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[contains(text(),'Export')])[1]"))
time.sleep(15)
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Interesting. How did you obtain the screenshot? Is there a way to see what Selenium is doing?
Also, this code gets me the same errors as before. No idea.

Comment: I disabled the `headless` mode.

Comment: please check webdriver options in my code below, it works, even with headless

Comment: Alright, this is at least some result to know its not possible. But how would they know that a software is being used?

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/33225947/7598774